# Algebraic Types - Haskell

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

I am working around with algebraic types in Haskell, doing some exercises from a worksheet. I got the following exercises:

> 1. Define an algebraic type Point for representing (the coordinates of) points in twodimensional space.

**My code for this exercise:**

```hs
data Point = Point Float Float
  deriving (Show)
```

> 2. Using Point, define a modified version PositionedShape of the Shape data type which
>      includes the centre point of a shape, in addition to its dimensions.

**Shape data previously defined:**

```hs
data Shape = Circle Float |
             Rectangle Float Float
             deriving (Show)
```

**My code for this exercise:**

```hs
data PositionedShape = PositionedShape Shape Point
  deriving (Show)
```

**Now my question comes in this one:**

> Define a function:
>
> `haskell move :: PositionedShape -> Float -> Float -> PositionedShape`
>
> which moves a shape by the given x and y distances

**My implementation for this was the following:**

```hs
move :: PositionedShape -> Float -> Float -> PositionedShape
move (Shape (Point x y)) newX newY = Shape (Point newX newY)
```

**This is returning me this error:**

> Week8.hs:103:7: error: Not in scope: data constructor ‘Shape’
>   Failed, modules loaded: none.

Can someone please explain me why this error and how can I solve it? I am getting a bit confused with algebraic types, I tried a lot of things but it just seems I can't get a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pattern match on data constructors (like `Circle` and `Rectangle`), not on type constructors as you're trying to do now (like `Shape`). For `PositionedShape`, they happen to have the same name, although you completely forgot the match on this one (and in fact, you don't need to care about the inner `Shape` at all except to copy it through). Also, `move` is meant to move the shape by the given distances, not to move it to a new given position.

Comment: Thank you very much! Bit of a dumb question but i'm a rookie in Haskell :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `PositionedShape` constructor to break apart a `PositionedShape`  You have used the `Shape` constructor instead.

Try starting with:

move (PositionedShape shape (Point old_x old_y)) [...]

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
move (PointedShape s (Point x y)) dx dy = PointedShape s (Point (x+dx) (y+dy))
```